# Replace specific letter in string

Tags: javascript, regex

If I want to replace a digit in the string, I would do the following:

```
"a3v".replace(/\d+/,"") // "av"
```

However, in the string "dynamic_fields[n][key]", I want to replace the n inside the brackets with 1. This is what I have done so far:

```
"dynamic_fields[n][key]".replace(/^.+[(n)]/,1)
```

Unfortunately, this is the result it gave me:

```
"1][key]"
```

Even though I expected:

```
"dynamic_fields[1][key]"
```

How come it doesn't recognize the capturing group () and replace the content in it with 1? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why are you trying to do this? Surely there must be a better option… it seems like you are perhaps trying to get the n-th element of an array, is it that?

Comment: .replace ("["+digit+"]",1.toString())

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant no, I need to do this because I send it to server  as part of params, and I need each name attribute incremented. n is just a placeholder.

Comment: Agree with @XristosK... also, when using RegEx, make sure to escape the brackets: `\[(n)\]`

Comment: @DanStayntouch then perhaps construct the string by doing something like `dynamic_fields[" + counter++ + "][key]"`.

Comment: `"dynamic_fields[n][key]".replace(/\[n\]/, '[1]')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be easily done like this:

```js
var string = "dynamic_fields[n][key]";
var replaced = string.replace(/\[n\]/,"\[1\]");
alert(replaced);
```

Basically, this finds the character "n" that is surrounded with brackets, and replaces it with a "1" surrounded with brackets.  Remeber to "escape" the brackets to make them literal. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#String_literals

I hope this helps!

Comment: I had this question too, and that fixed it for me!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it to be like that

```
"dynamic_fields[n][key]".replace(/[(n)]/g,1);
```

here's the sample running one

http://ideone.com/dzFGqQ